# How to dynamically add frames to GIF image with javascript

Tags: javascript, socket.io, streaming, gif, animated-gif

Say a browser has an animated gif displayed. Is it possible to dynamically add frames to that gif animation?

This superb gif is displayed in the browser

[image: Animated gif]

And this frame, received by the client from the server over socket.io, had to be added as the last frame of his gif :

[image: Animated gif individual frame]

(This was generated on the server using imageMagick and sent over socket.io)

```
convert animation.gif[3] animationFrame.gif
```

Socket.io sends the new frame to the client :

```
serverSocket.emit('newFrame, rawAnimationFrame);
```

Then the client receives it in raw format. BUT! Is there a library that could run in the browser that could allow me to do something like :

```
clientSocket.on('newFrame', function(frameData){
    superLibrary.addFrame(myGif, frameData);
})
```

If not, how could I achieve this?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: There's [**middleware**](https://github.com/rsms/node-imagemagick) for imageMagick in Node, I think that would be easier as the browser generally doesn't have write access for files hosted on the server etc.

Comment: Not on the server. The client would add frames sent by the server to his own downloaded gif.

Comment: I want to send the last frames only so that the client doesn't have to download the whole gif over and over again each time a new frame is added. It's like gif streaming.

Comment: I don't think there's any way to do that in a browser enviroment.

Comment: Try gif.js http://jnordberg.github.io/gif.js/

Comment: Posted issue on repo gif.js : https://github.com/jnordberg/gif.js/issues/25